# Procedure entry point could not be located Using QT with OpenCV and OpenCV_contrib in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017, OpenCV 3.2.0, OpenCV_contrib 3.2.0, QT 5.6.2, and CMake 3.8.2

I had made a program using OpenCV 3.2.0, and it worked previously, but I wanted to use the extra modules in OpenCV_contrib and the GUI in QT with my project, so I recompiled OpenCV with the above versions. I did not change the program at all yet, and when I run the program it builds but I get these two errors, then the program closes:

```
The procedure entry point
?toLower@QString@@QEHAA?AV1@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\QT\QT5.6.2\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin\QT5Test.dll
```

And I get this as well:

```
The procedure entry point
?toLatin1@QString@@QEGBA?AVQByteArray@@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\opencv\opencv\build\install\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_highgui320.dll.
```

I have also tried to build the program with

```
//#include<opencv/highgui.hpp>
```

commented, but I still get the second error.

I am not sure what this means, and I looked for the file in question and I found it, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do after that. Also, I am using Visual Studio when I get these pop up errors. I have not used QT Creator to create a project. This would be my first time.

Thank you.

Comment: Now this QT project?

Comment: You need to copy .dll files into working directory

Comment: I have copied opencv_highgui320.dll and Qt5Test.dll into myProject folder, but I am still getting the same error. I even went to project properties Configuration properties -> Linker -> General and added C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\projects\myProject\myProject in Additional Library Directories. And I am getting the same errors. Also, this is not a Qt project it is a Visual Studio Project that I am trying to use Qt features with.

Comment: And you intanavil Qt Visual Studio Tools???

Comment: [Visual Studio Add-in 2.0.0 for Qt5 MSVC 2015](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-tools-msvc2015-2.0.0.vsix)

Comment: And then open an empty project on the qt creator, then with the help of V Studio open the qt  project, automatically all the library qt at will